# Transferring python text output onto a google document

Tags: python, dictionary, google-docs

I am trying to create a mood tracker in which the python program will ask about certain question and then will come up with a quantitative value of how angry, surprised, happy, etc you are. I want the program to document the response and store it somewhere that I can access later on. Is there a way I can send the output to some place like a google document?

The output would be a string like:

```
"12/12/22 - Happy': 0.67, 'Angry': 0.0, 'Surprise': 0.33"
"12/13/22 - Happy': 0.58, 'Angry': 0.05, 'Surprise': 0.63"
```

etc

Personally, I thought about a dictionary within the code, but I realised it just resets every time I run the code again...

```py
class Documentation:
    def __init__(self, date, time, notes):
        self.date = date
        self.time = time
        self.notes = notes
        #self.journal = journal
    global journal
    journal = []  # list
    def time(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(now.year, now.month, now.day, now.hour, now.minute)
    def document(self, date,time, notes):
        journal.append((date, time, notes))
        print(journal)
    def allDocument(self, date, time, notes):
        for i in range(len(journal)):
            print(journal[i])
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and your goal. And, I cannot understand the relationship between `The output would be a string like: "12/12/22 - Happy': 0.67, 'Angry': 0.0, 'Surprise': 0.33" "12/13/22 - Happy': 0.58, 'Angry': 0.05, 'Surprise': 0.63" etc` and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And, if you want to put value to Google Documents, how about using Google Docs API? In this case, is this information useful? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)

Comment: How do you want the saved data accessed? locally or remotely? from your question, I feel like you just want to save the data somewhere.

Comment: The program will just output a string with the emotions values and I want to record it down as a text somewhere (like on a google doc so I can later access the notes from each day from a phone or another laptop). I was hoping to make a program to be an emotion tracker to see how someone's mood changes throughout the year.

Comment: Hi @Alvino123, Here's alternative articles that may help your goal: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/mwc8mq/today_i_finally_completed_my_first_python_project/ , https://hevodata.com/learn/python-to-google-sheets/ , https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-read-and-write-data-to-google-spreadsheet-using-python-ebf54d51a72c. These include how to connect API to python library. Note, that I am not affiliated with these articles, I just have searched through research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to [write it to a file](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp). You could try [writing it to Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python) but that's more complicated and not really designed for data storage. Your best bet is to do something like this with [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle

def save(filename, object):
    with open(filename, "wb") as file:
        pickle.dump(object, file)

def read(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as file:
        content = pickle.load(file)
    return content
```

Or, with [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp):

```
import json

def save(filename, object):
    with open(filename, "wt") as file:
        json.dump(object, file)

def read(filename):
    with open(filename, "rt") as file:
        content = json.load(file)
    return content
```

Example with pickle:

```
>>> save("data.bin", 123)
>>> read("data.bin")
123
```

Example with JSON:

```
>>> save("data.json", "foo")
>>> read("data.json")
'foo'
```